# Suggestions for an android and java book

Tags: android

I am looking for some recommendations for a book for my situation. I am an electrical engineer, with programming experience using a LISP based proprietary language called SKILL. I do not have much experience in Object Oriented Programming (other than a C++ course I took about 10yrs ago when I was in school). That said I want to develop some android apps for some ideas I have and put them in the android market. I have downloaded the development environment and run the Hello World program.

1. Where should I begin with serious app development?
2. Book suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

1. Learn Java
2. Any Android book will do when you're starting.

Answer (score 1):

1 Learn Java: I've started with "O Reilly: Learning Java"
 ([available here](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565927186.do)). It is quite complete and it did the job for me.

2 Learn Android: I suggest that you read (almost) the entire Guide section of the Android Developers'site: http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html. That helps a lot.

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is go for

1) Learn Java fundamentals and core concepts from "Java 2 Complete Reference" book. 
2) You are already having a development setup to start and Start Android coding with the help of http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html.
 If you stuck up somewhere while playing around Programmers from StackOverflow will help you to understand!

Life is simple!

Answer (score 1):

At my university we have an entire 2 year program for Android. The starting courses are doing this as duffymo and Zoleas has suggested, first a Java primer course and then we are using

- [Conder, Darcey: Android Wireless Application Development, Addison Wesley. 978-0-321-74301-5](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321813839).

For actual android applications. The first impressions are promising.